# Trouble connecting Visual Studio to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have the MySQL connector and I can see my MySQL database in the server explorer, I'm able to create tables and stuff... but when I try to access it through `SqlConnection` or `SqlCeConnection` I get error 40 or the one in the image

[image]

In English it means error while trying to access object reference data not defined to an instance of an object.

Comment: That's a null reference exception, then. What line is it occurring on?

Comment: check your connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well:

- `SqlConnection` is for **Microsoft SQL Server** only
- `SqlCeConnection` is for **Microsoft SQL Server CE (Compact Edition)** only

You need to use the `MySqlConnection` to connect to MySQL !

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use SqlConnection to connect MySql. This will not work this way. You need a [Mysql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) Library to use MySql Database.

Simply Every Sql (kind of class and method) prefix with 'My'. Like SqlConnection to MySqlConnection.

Answer (score 1):

can you please add Mysql.Data.MysqlClient;
before that add reference to the source "Mysql.Data","Mysql.Web"
Change "MySqlConnection"  instead of "SqlConnection".